# How do I fix this, trying to call database entry with $GET data?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to sent data through a link, using the ...?id=3 in the link for example. Than i use GET in php to retrieve it. But when i try to put it in a query it doesn't work

```
$select= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id= $_GET['id'] ");
```

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO instead. You are a lot safer then.

Comment: I'm assuming the connection to the DB is okay and everything. What doesn't work exactly? What error are you getting? 

If you use regular variables does it work fine?

Comment: @WizKid thanks for the advise but I im in some time constraint, i dont have time to pick it up. do u know what might me wrong or the right way to do it in mysql.

Comment: @Patrick yea if i put in a number instead it works fine

Comment: Wrap "... `{$_GET['id']} ..."` in quotes - bearing in mind this adds a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @halfer thanks that worked never seen that before tho

Comment: Without it, it believes the variable is `$_GET`, since square brackets are not legal variable identifiers. It's a way of telling PHP what the full expression is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that the variable is an integer, otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$select= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id= $id");
```

PHP does allow simple variable references inside quoted strings, but not an array reference like you're doing. You can do complex variable interpolation by enclosing the expression in curly braces like @user3624411 suggest... but **please don't**. That's still vulnerable to SQL injections, and you must not do it. If you were an electrician, you would be guilty of causing a fire by installing unsafe wiring.

Ideally you would switch to PDO and use query parameters, and I encourage you to learn about that at the first opportunity. But I understand you're under a time constraint and it's not practical to rewrite all your database code.

Comment: thanks for your help, with this i am using a link to get to a curtain product, its for a e-commerce site. This just so i can open selected product on a php page. Do think your method is safe enough.

Comment: Yes, it forces `$id` to be an integer, and that prevents any malicious content from sneaking into your SQL. You really need to learn about how SQL injection works and how to protect yourself. I recommend [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) (my presentation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$select= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id= '$id' ");
```

or you can use `$select= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id= " .$_GET['id'] . ")";`

But I offer you don't use GET method and MYSQL: use POST and MYSQLI or PDO.

Comment: Whether GET or POST, this is still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah just because the variable isn't `$_GET` from the URL, users can still insert data into the `$_POST` variable.  MySQLi and PDO prepared statements will protect you most times from SQL injection, POST will not.